# How to show a div by clicking on the table row in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am making an app using Angular 2. 
There is one table using `*ngFor` of Angular 2. Code is like below,

```
<tr *ngFor="let l of league">
            <td>{{l.position}}</td>
            <td> <img [src]="l.crestURI" [alt]="l.teamName" width="50px" height="50px"><a href="#" (click)="getTeams(l._links.team.href); showPlayers == true">{{l.teamName}}</a>              </td>
            <td>{{l.playedGames}}</td>
            <td>{{l.wins}}</td>
            <td>{{l.losses}}</td>
            <td>{{l.points}}</td>
            <td>{{l.goals}}</td>
            <td>{{l.goalsAgainst}}</td>
            <td>{{l.goalDifference}}</td>
          </tr>
```

Now I want to show the players info of the particular team after clicking the name of the team in such a way that only the particular team's players will be there. And on the click of the team name again/ click some other team name it would be hidden.

I call the service to get the players info of the team correctly. But get confused how to show using Angular 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how you api is achieving the data but if the league is coming with array of teams, and the team has an array of players, then that's easy.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let team of teams; let i = index">
     <td>{{team.position}}</td>
     <td>{{team.teamName}}</td>
     <td (click)="itemsVisibility[i] = !itemsVisibility[i]">
         {{team.teamName}}
         <div *ngIf="itemsVisibility[i]">
            <p *ngFor="let player of team.players"></p>
         </div>
     </td>
     ...
     <td>{{l.points}}</td>
 </tr>
```

That's the core of the idea, then if you want to close the rest players once you click on another team would be like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/u2YE2EvH0W7pmOKrDb44?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Even if it's not the same structure of data (surely it's not) that's how its done with Angular, so you can adapt it on the way you get the data, but definitely I would suggest you to do not call the api in every click for getting the players, in which case you need to think what about if the user is clicking all the time? delays? data consuming? ;)